# intersections and unions of families of open sets

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $F_j$ is a collection of open balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $j\in J$, where $J$ is a countable index-set.

Let

$A_1 := \text{int}\bigcap_{j\in J}\left( \bigcup_{B\in F_j} B \right)$ and
$A_2 := \bigcup_{B\in \cap_{j\in J} F_j}B$.

I am trying to investigate if $A_1 = A_2$.

I know that $A_2\subseteq A_1$. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are open so it suffices to check for an arbitrary open ball $B'\subseteq A_2$. Then there exists $\{B_k\}_{k=1}^\infty \subseteq \cap_{j\in J}F_j$ such that $B' = \cup_{k=1}^\infty B_k$. Thus $B'\subseteq \cup_{B\in F_j} B$ for all $j\in J$, and therefore also in the intersection.

I have not been able to prove $A_1\subseteq A_2$, but I have not been able to construct a counter example either. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Ok I just found a very simple counter example. Let $J = \{1,2\}$ with $F_1 = \{B_1\}$ and $F_2 = \{B_2\}$ for $B_1\neq B_2$ but $B_1\cap B_2\neq \emptyset$.

Then $A_1 = B_1\cap B_2 \neq \emptyset = A_2$.

So let me rephrase the question. Are there some mild conditions on the $F_j$ families such that $A_1\subseteq A_2$?

One easy case is if $F_{j} = F_{j'}$ for all $j,j'\in J$.

Could something similar hold if we let $J = \mathbb{N}$ and assume $\cap_{j=1}^\infty F_j \neq \emptyset$ and $F_{j+1}\subseteq F_{j}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equality may fail to hold even under the assumption that $$F_\infty:=\bigcap_jF_j\ne\varnothing,\quad F_{j+1}\subset F_j.$$ To see this just fix $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and take $F_j$ to be $$F_j=\{B(\pm x,|x|)\}\cup \{B(\pm x,|x|+2^{-k})\ |\  k\ge j\}.$$ Then $A_1$ contains the origin, whereas $A_2$ does not (in fact their difference is precisely the origin).

By adding the collection $$\{B(\pm x', |x'|+2^{-k}\ | \ \ k\ge j\}$$ to the union defining $F_j$ for some $x'\ne x$ one can even make the difference $A_1\setminus A_2$ have positive measure.